# QListWidgetItems added successfully and recognised at index but do not load (with other odd properties)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I recently have been developing a project that involves adding events to an eventlist and then being to able to run these events. All development has been smooth sailing until this odd occurrence.

I have a list containing a couple events I wwant to add to the eventlist like this:
in main.py:

```
def loadInformation(self, eventListContents, eventParams):
    print(f'| - loadInformation.eventListContents [info] adding events {eventListContents}')
    self.eventList.insertItems(0, eventListContents)
    self.items=[]
    for index in range(self.eventList.count()): self.items.append(self.eventList.item(index).text())
    print(f'| - loadInformation.eventListContents [info] self.eventList now == {self.items}')
    print(f'| - loadInformation.eventListContents [info] adding params {eventParams}')
    self.eventList.update()
    paramLinkedToIndex = eventParams
```

in loader.py:

```py
# Import PyQt5 Modules
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

# Import Modules
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread
from re import search

# Local Libraries
from lib.MalMakerLib import MalMakerEventScripts as mmlib
from main import ScriptWindow

class openFile:
    def __init__(self):
        super(openFile, self).__init__()
        
        self.handleMalFileUpload(QFileDialog().getOpenFileName(caption='Open MalMaker Project', filter='MalMaker Projects (*.mal)'))

    def handleMalFileUpload(self, file):
        print(f'| - openFile.handleMalFileUpload() [info] got file {file[0]}')
        with open(file[0], 'r') as f:
            self.fileData = f.read()
            self.lines = self.fileData.split('\n')
            count = 0
            print(f'| - openFile.handleMalFileUpload() [info] data from file:\n{self.fileData}')
            print(f'| - openFile.handleMalFileUpload() [info] seperated lines of file: {self.lines}')
            for line in self.lines:
                count+=1
                if count in range(4):
                    print(f'| - openFile.handleMalFileUpload()::line-interpreter [info] skipped on line {count}')
                    pass
                if count == 5:
                    eventListContents = eval(line.split('=')[1])
                    print(f'| - openFile.handleMalFileUpload()::line-interpreter [info] got eventListContents: {eventListContents}')
                if count == 6:
                    eventParams = eval(line.split('=')[1])
                    print(f'| - openFile.handleMalFileUpload()::line-interpreter [info] got eventParams: {eventParams}')
                elif count >= 7:
                    print(f'| - openFile.handleMalFileUpload()::line-interpreter [info] skipped on line {count}')
                    pass
        ScriptWindow().loadInformation(eventListContents, eventParams)
```

For your information, eventList was created using qt designer and addItems() works in all other functions but this one.

However, I am facing issue where it prints that it added the items successfully at the index but will not appear, even after calling .update(), and will disappear shortly after.

A factor that may be causing this is the fact that I calling this function from another file and am passing self by initializing the class then calling it, but it does report that there items at the index when I request it in the third print statement.

Here is the code that calls this function: `ScriptWindow().loadInformation(eventListContents, eventParams)`

Also, a possible factor is the file strucutre, which looks something like this:

```
+ My App:
| - main.py
| + lib:
  | - loader.py
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mre].